# Design a web only for iPhone

Tags: iphone, mobile, mobile-safari

I want to design a web specifically for iPhone. 
I design directly with the sizes of the iPhone in portrait mode: width:320px; height:356px;
I have a logo with a png
I put the viewport in the head:
`<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width">`

http://jsfiddle.net/u2rbj/

It works fine in portrait mode, but in landscape it scales everything even the png and it looses resolution. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configure the viewport for your webpage using special tags made specifically for iOS and other mobile platforms. Take a loot at [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html).

Comment: Yes, I read this before make the question and I put the tag: <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width"> Then it comes the problem in landscape